# Checking user logged in state and loading view controllers based on it using Firebase and Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3

I am working on an enterprise app in swift 3. When user loads the app, I would like to check if the user is already signed in or not. If the user is already signed in , user is taken to the `Home view controller` else a `login screen` is shown.

This workflow works perfectly fine. When I register a new user using `SignUp` button, user info is stored in Firebase and a message is displayed to  user:

```
 “A email will be send to you after verification of your identity”.
```

Now, If I close the app and loads it again, a `Home view controller` is showed for the user which has just signed up and never logged in. I am stuck at this point, as for the newly signed up user I want to show the `login view controller` so that he can login from there. But instead he app is showing directly `Home view controller`. I would appreciate any leads here.

Below is my code which is in AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

    launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FIRApp.configure()

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
    if currentUser != nil
    {
       self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController")
    }
    else
    {
        self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController")

    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

User's instance is there, but then you need to check if the user's email address is verified or not.

Use currentUser.emailVerified for that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried with currentUser.Isemailverified. If its a yes, app still takes user directly to home view controller instead of login view controller

Comment: Where did you put that condition?

Comment: In AppDelegate in the above function as follow

Comment: if (currentUser?.isEmailVerified)!{
            




         
            
            
           self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomTabBarID")
        }
            
        else
            
        {
            self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewID")
            
        }
        
        }

Comment: There can be many scenarios... Can you retry with the login view controller placed in another storyboard?